# jQuery .effect('shake') doesn't work on Safari and Firefox

Tags: jquery, forms, firefox, safari

I made this: http://jsfiddle.net/jalxob/ahQLC/18/

```
    $( ".formbox" ).effect('shake', { times:2, distance:5 });
```

It works well on Chrome but not in Safari and Firefox.

Can someone please help me?

If you check on Safari you will notice that when the all or one of the inputs are not filled, a red shadow around the input appears and the container divs shakes a little. The red shadow doesn't appear and the shaking changes dramatically on Safari and Firefox.

Thank you :)

Comment: Removing auto from margin in formbox class seems to fix the shakiness. So it appears to be some Cross-browser css compatability problem

Comment: Yes, it makes it works. But I need it center that way :(

Answer (score 0):

I just add -webkit-appearance: none; and it works now.

I still need to figure it how the shaking doesnt look good on Safari and Firebox. 
It only works when you delate the auto margin but I need it center.